# Http Posting An Image From Iphone

Tags: http, uiimage, nsurlconnection

NSMutableString *url = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [url appendString:@"uploadImage.do"];

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(selectedImage,1.0);


// setting up the request object now
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

/*
 add some header info now
 we always need a boundary when we post a file
 also we need to set the content type

 You might want to generate a random boundary.. this is just the same
 as my output from wireshark on a valid html post
 */
NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"nickname\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:appDelegate.userName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"password\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:appDelegate.passWord] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userImage\"\r\n\r\n" ] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
//[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userImage\"; filename=\"Default.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
//[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
//[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
//[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


[request setHTTPBody:body];

// now lets make the connection to the web
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (theConnection) {

    receivedData=[[NSMutableData data] retain];

}
else {

    NSLog(@"Failed");

}
```

i am using this code to upload an image to server. i am doing as stated below 
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(selectedImage,1.0);

i am getting nsdata object which is not nill. but if i post it the server side i am getting null been sent as params.

any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found out a way for doing this.

save the image you got in your local directory and then send it as a file by giving its full path......